# Lambda expressions to obtain data through navigation properties, LINQToEntities

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm having a problem getting some data since I'm just starting to use LINQToEntities, Entity Framework and Lambda Expressions.

Let me explain my case:

I have a database with 4 tables as shown here:

[image: Database diagram]

when I generate the model from database in Visual Studio (2010) the result is this:

[image: Model in Visual Studio]

I searched for some info and turns out that since the table t_user_role only has the ids from its two parent tables, it gets abstracted in the model, and you have to use the navigation properties instead.

I had some problem getting the role info for a user on a given system (as the next function does)

```cs
    public t_role GetRoleForUser(string userId, string sysId)
    {
        entities = new secfinEntities(); //context from the model

        t_role userRole = entities.t_role.Where(r => r.t_user.Any(u => u.uid == userId) & r.sys_id == sysId).First();

        return userRole;
    }
```

Now I have to implement a simple search function that will look users that contain the provided string and return the user's id and name (uid, user_name) and their role's info (role_id, role_name) on a given system (the system info i have beforehand), so basically I wanna turn this next SQL Query into Lambda Expressions (keeping in mind that in the model the table t_user_role has been abstracted)

```sql
SELECT U.uid, U.user_name, R.role_id, R.role_name
FROM t_user U
    INNER JOIN t_user_role UR ON U.uid = UR.uid
    INNER JOIN t_role R ON UR.role_id = R.role_id
WHERE R.sys_id = @p0 -- first parameter
    AND U.user_name LIKE '%' + @p1 + '%' -- second parameter
```

Also, I would like to store the results of that in a List of a type I have defined as follows:

```cs
public class UserRole
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public UserRole(string uid, string uname, string rid, string rname)
    {
        UserId = uid;
        UserName = uname;
        RoleId = rid;
        RoleName = rname;
    }
}
```

So after explaining what I have done and what I'm trying to do first question is: how can that be done?, second: can the same be accomplished through the verbose form instead of Lambda expressions? if yes, how?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time.

Comment: +1 for providing exactly the info we require to help you out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This T-SQL:

```
SELECT U.uid, U.user_name, R.role_id, R.role_name 
FROM t_user U 
    INNER JOIN t_user_role UR ON U.uid = UR.uid 
    INNER JOIN t_role R ON UR.role_id = R.role_id 
WHERE R.sys_id = @p0 -- first parameter 
    AND U.user_name LIKE '%' + @p1 + '%' -- second parameter
```

given your model translates to this verbose syntax (including the requirement to use your new model):

```
var results = (from u in entities.t_user
              from r in u.t_role
              where r.sys_id == sysIdVariable && u.user_name.Contains(userNameVariable)
              select new UserRole(u.uid, u.user_name, r.role_id, r.role_name))
```

I know you didn't ask for it, but a lambda version might look like:

```
var results = entities.t_user.Join(entities.t_role, 
                                   x => x.t_role_id, 
                                   x => x.role_id, 
                                  (u, r) => new UserRole(u.uid, 
                                                         u.user_name, 
                                                         r.role_id, 
                                                         r.role_name))
```

Comment: Ok now i feel ashamed because it was so simple and i initially thought it could only be accomplished with lambda expressions... although this is the first time i've seen 2 froms like that, what does that do exactly?

Comment: It's (in this example) shorthand for doing a join when a navigation property exists for the relationship.  The alternative would have been (please excuse code in comment box...) `from u in entities.t_user join r in entities.t_role on u.t_role_id == r.role_id where....`   You can also use it for joining _unrelated_ entities because you could specify different keys to join them on etc.  Don't be ashamed though, the good news is your question was the best read I've seen on the site all week! :-)

Comment: Well I took my sweet time to make sure I included every detail possible because I didn't want to be pulling my hair longer than needed. And thanks for the explanation, I will keep that in mind for the future :)